# Interpreting the Crow's foot ER symbols

Tags: entity-relationship

I came to know that there is Crow's foot ER diagram notation, and got a good quick reference. Have a look at the below diagram:

[image]

I did get some clarity on these symbols, however I have difficulty in understanding:

1) Why we have the "connector symbols" on both side of the line?

2) How to interpret them?

Can anyone please help me understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reference is somewhat incorrect. The Entity-Relationship model doesn't use Crow's foot. Chen's notation and extensions to that notation can be called ER diagrams.

Your diagram is a generalization of table diagrams, modified to allow many-to-many associations and hide attributes. However, it doesn't represent relationships using their own shapes, and I see no indication of support for ternary or higher relationships. There's also no indication of other ER concepts like weak entities, associative entities, identifying relationships or keys.

Data models that only support binary relationships are usually based on the network data model, not on the Entity-Relationship model. Relationships in the ER model, when physically implemented, are represented by two or more entity columns in the same table, not by any kind of link between tables. In actual table diagrams, many-to-many relationships are represented by their own table, with two one-to-many association lines. In those cases, the cardinality indicators represent the number and optionality of records with matching values for matching PK/FK columns.

The interpretation of the Crow's foot symbols are indicated in the orange column. For more information about modeling with Crow's foot, see [Entity Modelling](http://www.entitymodelling.org). However, don't confuse this with the Entity-Relationship model as described by Chen, or either of them with the Relational model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if this is not correct, then what is the correct place to look for these information? Could you please help in this?

Comment: It depends on which model of data you want to use. For entity-relationship modeling, the best place to start is with Chen's paper `The Entity-Relationship Model - Toward a Unified View of Data`. Understanding the model behind the notation will make the diagrams and notation much easier to understand and remember. If you search online for "entity-relationship model", look for results on sites of educational institutions (.edu).

Comment: For the relational model of data, Codd's paper `A Relational Model of Data for Large Shared Data Banks` is a good read. A good book is `Applied Mathematics for Database Professionals` by Lex de Haan and Toon Koppelaars.

Another good approach is Object-Role modeling (http://orm.net).