# UML class diagram relationship use strange symbols

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have such a childish problem. I have such a class diagram and the main problem is that I have never seen this type of uml class notation. Therefore, at the moment I am at a loss as to what these signs mean. And until I find out, I can't really start doing anything. If someone could explain them, I would be very grateful or direct me to where I can read more about these signs.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interpreting the Crow's foot ER symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483578/interpreting-the-crows-foot-er-symbols)

Comment: Some comments on the diagram itself: It's a best practice to name entities (or table) using the singular form, so prefer **Order** over **orders**. I think the multiplicities are not correct. According to your diagram, a product can only be included in a single orderdetail, and an order can have only one orderdetail.

Answer (score 4):

This is simply not UML but ERD (Entity Relationship Diagram). See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model)

As [Christophe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3723423/christophe) mentioned, yours is [crow's foot notation](https://vertabelo.com/blog/crow-s-foot-notation/) while Wikipedia is using Chen's. More about the notation above in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483578/interpreting-the-crows-foot-er-symbols) as [Geert Bellekens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2018133/geert-bellekens) found out.

Comment: More specifically, it’s [crow’s foot notation](https://vertabelo.com/blog/crow-s-foot-notation/) of ERD, not to be confused with Chen’s notation used in the wikipedi article ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Christophe. As I mentioned in the deleted quuestion part, I'm no expert in that area (only by hear-and-say :) Will update the answer.